# How to display text from a file

Tags: javascript, html, text, label

I have a text file on my server, which I would like to display in a Label (or similar element).
What is the best way to do this? If possible, I would like it to be formatted the same way as it is in the text file.

(I was thinking it would be similar to using "src" for images, but turns out you can't do that).

Comment: You can use fetch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401390/promises-fetch-in-javascript-how-to-extract-text-from-text-file

Comment: What kind of server? What code do you have already? How are you passing data to your front end.

Comment: @FivePlyPaper maybe "server" is a bit misleading. It is a file sitting in a folder beside my HTML

Comment: @Stiegi I've tried this method and there is an error claiming "URL scheme "file" is not supported.".
Is there no way to make this work locally too?

Comment: You have to spin up a HTTP server to make it work with fetch

Comment: So then is there just 1 word in the text file or are you just wanting its contents in a <p> tag?

Answer (score 1):

I would try reading the file with PHP, process the text (split in parts, cut, whatever) and set up an array with the required texts.You can call it later with using the array.

Finally ur code should look something like this:

```
<img src="<?=$arrayText['test1]?>" class=".." alt="...">
```

**More information**

PHP read .txt files:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp

Several functions for processing strings:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.strings.php

Several functions for using arrays in PHP:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.array.php

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a local web server (NodeJS, Python, etc.) to serve your local assets and then either render the HTML file dynamically (eg: via Express for NodeJS) or make a [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) request (eg: `fetch('/path/to/file.txt')`)